# How should I split an image into sections with a pure OpenCV function, so I don't have to take it off my GPU?

Tags: python, opencv, split

Consider:

```
def split(img: cv2.UMat) -> cv2.UMat:
    img = img.get()
    images = []
    i = 0
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    while i < height:
        section = np.random.randint(5, 20)
        image = img[i:min(i+section, height), :, :]   # <-- grr
        images.append(cv2.UMat(image))
        i += section

    return cv2.vconcat(images)
```

I'm trying to split an image into multiple horizontal sections of random height, and I'd like to figure out a way to do this without having to use `img.get()` and pull the frame off of my GPU (I'm playing with filtering a webcam stream, and this is quite a performance hit).